# Deviant Rust: how can I disable all the warnings and checks possible?

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, warnings, dangerous-request

Let's assume I wanted to write horrific and evil *code* that compiled with `rustc`. How many compiler-checks, type-checks, and warnings can I disable without recompiling Rust? And how would I go about doing it?

I'm looking for the Perl equivalent of `no warnings; no strict;`

---

Obviously I know this isn't good advice. I want to understand the configuration options of `rustc` the fun way.

Comment: Allow, this kind of code would make any rust compiler not compliant, you ask the exact contrary that rust do. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: "Type checking" isn't really the kind of thing you can turn off; it's fundamental to how the compiler understands your code. Code that doesn't type check isn't merely *unsafe*, it's *nonsensical*. Some warnings can be turned off, mostly those considered "lints", but most of them are part of the type system -- there's simply no reason for them to have an off-switch.

Comment: Great question. No good reason for any compiler to enforce style.  Fight authoritarianism wherever it rears its ugly head.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be to silence warnings, and any unused arguments, etc. with `#![allow(warnings, unused)]`. However, I don't believe you can disable type checks or other compile errors: doing so would be pretty antithetical to a compiler's purpose. You would likely need to generate a syntax tree and then remove any errors by deleting lines from the source until the code compiles (or based on error suggestions), similar to how [fuckitpy](https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy) works.

For example, to silence all warnings, etc.:

```
#![allow(warnings, unused)]

unsafe fn iHaTeReAdAbLeCoDe(arg: u8, unused_arg: u32) -> u8 {
    let x: i32;
    arg
}

pub fn main() {
    print!("{:?}", unsafe {

                iHaTeReAdAbLeCoDe(5, 0)
    });
}
```

Please don't do this.